# Paypal TLS1.2 / Http1.1 Upgrade - HTML Form Basics for PayPal Payments Standard

Tags: c#, paypal

So i'm trying to take action on paypals PCI requirements
https://www.paypal-notice.com/en/TLS-1.2-and-HTTP1.1-Upgrade/

They have informed me that I need to update to using TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade

So Im using just the basic Basics html PayPal Payments Standard and have a basic checkout option to allow clients to pay for their stuff.
My web application is running .Net4.5 and using https.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
//Stuff
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.net/Paypal" />
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online." class="subscription" id="btngo">
</form>
```

So as far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correct?
Has anyone else gone through this upgrade and tell me what I'm missing?
Perhaps I need to do something on my notify_url?

Comment: Is that all of your integration? If so, I don't see any problem, because you're moving the responsibility to support TLS 1.2 and HTTP 1.1 to the client browser. Anyway PayPal offers sandbox accounts you can test with.

Comment: This is more of a server related configuration problem and nothing to do with your code. How are you hosting your app?

Comment: Using IIS, when I do a TLS Check on the webserver it says TLS1.2 is supported

Comment: are you making a request to paypal server-side? note: your code above shows a HTTP form mechanism that will have the client/user-agent (browser) post; so it means the browser itself needs to support tls version 1.2 ..

Comment: Why the [c#] tag? This is just an HTTP form that posts to Paypal. If the *browser* is up to date (all major browsers are) it already works with TLS 1.2. If it isn't, there's nothing you can do anyway. You should probably configure your web application/IIS so *it* requires the use of TLS 1.2 as well

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be asking you if your Webserver configuration is in order. You can use a few external tools to ensure you are PCI compliant in that regard but I believe it's just ensuring you've got TLS 1.2 and HTTP 1.1 enabled.

You can test TLS 1.2 is configured correctly using  [Qualsys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

Otherwise if you want your server to disable ciphers and protocols that may not be secure then you can use a tool like [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) which is a streight forward way to do it.

If you don't want your site to be hit externally at the moment you can check your server using openssl on a Linux box it can give you some great diagnostic info. For ease of use however I'd stick with SSL Labs.

Word of warning however, if your web server is running older versions of Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL Server or other software be careful disabling older cipher suits (Like some of the TLS protocols) as they often rely upon those cipher suites for connectivity (including remote desktop). There are fixes out there but take time to plan it out.

Other from that if SSL Labs gives you a green light then your compliant.

**UPDATE**

If you can see https://tlstest.paypal.com from your webserver and it shows that the TLS check is ok then that should be all you need to do. As you are using PayPal Basics they'll automatically upgrade their endpoints to TLS 1.2 for your code. The HTTPS part in your form is the important bit.

I imagine for older web servers establishing a TLS 1.2 connection between PayPal and the server might fail and that's what they want you to check.

Comment: Hey Joey, thank you for the response, yes I used Qualsys and they gave me the green light for TLS1.2 and Http 1.1, (even before the paypal check) so still struggle why i got that recommendation from paypal as I seem to tick every box?

Comment: @D-W I've updated the answer to reflect your comment. They'll be sending that notification out to all Pay Pal users regardless of their intergration as they are not going to test your webserver. If they disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 support (which I guess they are doing) then your code would simply break if you didn't support the newer version of TLS. It's a courtesy on their part to let you know what they are doing.

Comment: unless you only accept tls version 1.2 to visitors of your site - you'll likely have a case scenario where a visitor/client using an older browser will fail this workflow. In part, that is why everyone gets a notice about this - gracefully messages to the client - not just a server to server consideration.  You can make an application/json request to sites like https://www.howsmyssl.com/ to check whether a client does support 1.2.  For, as far as I know, there is no module in IIS and/or ASP.NET that will provide you TLS version information of the request from a client browser;

Comment: @BrettCaswell if OP was to support TLS 1.2 and clients are regularly connecting to his site using browsers that dont support TLS 1.2 isn't it right that it should fail? TLS 1.2 has been a standard for long enough for people to be up to date by now. OP would infact have to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 support to allow this configuration to fully work?

Comment: Just to Confirm My webservers do not support TLS1.0/1.1

Comment: @D-W makes sense there then. If a client was using an older browser they simply wouldn't be able to connect and your PayPal transactions would be protected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting 4.5 framework TLS1.2 is enabled but not the default. 4.6.2+ target does default TLS1.2 I believe you can add this to force it:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing funny going on there. You just need to make sure that the page you're hosting the form from, is secured by TLS1.2 encryption.

If you're someone who does SSL offloading before your actual web server (like some load balancer), that also is practically fine.

Good luck with the upgrade!

Comment: Using IIS, when I do a TLS Check on the webserver it says TLS1.2 is supported, any other way I can confirm this?

Comment: @D-W A more straightforward check would be to access your public URL using a browser or using curl via command line.


`curl -v -I GET 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/'`

where you can replace 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/' with your public URL.